# Editing fillable PDF files on a JavaScript page

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

Is there any library that I could use to display fillable PDF on my web page that will allow user to **fill** the form and **submit** changes (save)? Ideally in JavaScript.

I was looking for similar questions but my case is more complicated that the ones I found as my page allows users to upload any fillable document - so there is no specific format.

I would be thankful for any hint.

Answer (score 0):

If your server could convert the uploaded documents to ODF, you could use [WebODF](http://webodf.org/)

Comment: I would like to avoid that as I would have to convert the file twice, PDF->ODT and ODT->PDF. Not sure whether there is a library to convert it and have at the end 1) same looking PDF file 2) still fillable 3) does WebODF offer editing only selected fields? Overcomplicated.. But still it's an option.